# Can't make a toast from thread in an AppWidgetProvider class

Tags: android, toast, android-appwidget, android-context

I have an appwidget that can download some data from a web service (in a thread in `onReceive()` ) by clicking on it. After that is finished the GUI of the widget gets updated in `updateWidget(...)` (= re-drawn).

I want to make a toast when this is done. I tried a lot like to make a toast at the end of `updateWidget(...)` by passing the context from the thread to the toast, but that didn't work. The problem seems to be the context. Because my class inherits from `AppWidgetProvider` and NOT from Activity I CANNOT use stuff like `getApplicationContext()`. I guess I just need to get the right context for the toast, but I have no idea how to do that.

Here is the relevant code:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    //  Name of the action of the intent
    final String action = intent.getAction();

    //  This way the context and the intent can be used in the thread
    final Context ctx = context;
    final Intent i = intent;

    if (action.equals(COUNT_DOWN) == true || action.equals(COUNT_UP) == true)
    {
        //  Show toast to inform the user that this feature is only available in the full version
        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.no_groupchange, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    // Update current group
    else if (action.equals(UPDATE_WIDGET))
    {
        // Check for internet connection
        if (isOnline(context) == true)
        {
            //  Show toast to inform the user that refreshing the data has started
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.refreshing, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //  This way the complete internet communication is independent from the GUI
            //  Also works at low speed internet connection
            Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int currentGroupOrderID = soapManager.getCurrentGroupOrderID(LEAGUE_SC);
                    theGroup = soapManager.getGroup(currentGroupOrderID, LEAGUE_SC, SAISON);
                    nextMatch = soapManager.getNextMatch(LEAGUE_SC);

                    updateWidget(ctx, i);                       
                }
            });

            myThread.start();               
        } 
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.no_internet, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}

public void updateWidget(Context context, Intent intent)
{           
    //  Creating remoteViews for updating the widget
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout_simple);

    //  Fill the textViews with text
    setTextViewsFromTheGroup(remoteViews);
    setNextMatchTextView(remoteViews);

    //  Update the widget
    ComponentName widget = new ComponentName(context, SoccerWidgetProvider.class);
    AppWidgetManager awm = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    awm.updateAppWidget(widget, remoteViews);

    //  This way the widget doesn't stop reacting after some time
    final int appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);

    if (appWidgetId != AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID)
    {
        attachIntents(context, remoteViews, appWidgetId);
    }

    //  HERE I WANT TO MAKE A TOAST!!!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `Toast.makeText` from the UI thread. You can do that by doing:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run()
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.refreshing, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: There is no `runOnUiThread` on `AppWidgetProvider` instance neither